# Display total of one column based on group by on another table | RDLC Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

```
Id | Name | Value
-----------------
1  | Abcd | 20
1  | Abcd | 30
1  | Abcd | 40
1  | Abcd | 50
2  | efgh | 8
2  | efgh | 7
```

I am having data as above and I want to display data in RDLC report and it should be like following:

```
Id | Name | Value
-----------------
1  | Abcd | 140
2  | efgh | 15
```

That is `Value` column should bind the sum of values group by `Name`.

Kindly help me out.